# forcing keyword arguments in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, keyword-argument

I know I can use `*` to force all keyword arguments to a function/method to be "named".

If I have

```
def abc(a, *, x=10, z=30):
    pass
```

then the following all work

```
abc(5)
abc(8, x=12)
abc(9, z=31)
abc(x=17, a=4)
```

even if I change the function signature to `def abc(a, *, x=10, y=20, z=30)`, 
and

```
abc(7, 13)
```

throws an error.

This is extremely important because, I can use the logical place, which will help maintenance over time, without being forced to use the end position based on history.

But * is not valid in Python 2.7, and `abc(a, *args, x=10, z=30)` (which I tried) doesn't work either.

Is there a way to force the use of `x=12` in Python 2.7? Or another way of saying: make `abc(7, 13)` be invalid on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this is by adding a dummy keyword argument that never gets a valid positional value (so don't check for `None`):

```
_dummy = object()

def abc(a, dummy_kw=_dummy, x=10, z=30):
    if dummy_kw is not _dummy:
        raise TypeError("abc() takes 1 positional argument but at least 2 were given")
```

That will prohibit `abc(7, 13)` and allow all the others. *It works on Python 2 and Python 3, so it is useful when you have code that needs to run on both.*

Originally I used:

```
 def _dummy():
    pass
```

but as @mata pointed out `_dummy=object()` works as well, and cleaner. Essentially any unique memory location that is not used in another way will work.

Comment: I was about to write that `*dummy_kw` doesn't work in Python 3, but you update the answer already. This looks nice..

Comment: Why do you use a function as dummy? Usually you'd use `_dummy = object()` for such a case. Other then that, +1 for the answer

Comment: @mata Thanks for the tip, that does work as well (and is a line shorter).

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
def abc(a, **kwargs):
    # Get arguments from kwargs otherwise use default values
    x = kwargs.pop('x', 10) 
    z = kwargs.pop('z', 30) 

    if not kwargs: # if kwargs is not empty
        print 'extra parameters passed'

    pass
```

This allows to force the use of kwargs and still have default values.

`pop` removes the key from `kwargs`, once you use it.
This is potentially very useful as you can check if the user gave extra parameters that do not belong to the function and in this case you can throw an error (for example).

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo

Comment: That is what I assumed. I used this before I got to the method in my answer, it is IMO nicer when you have a lot of parameters, and smart editors still can make a function/method signature out of it.