# How to use `@dataclass` decorator within a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-dataclasses

I would like to create a class decorator to pre-define some attributes and methods to decorated class. At the same time, I would like that this decorated class be decorated with `@dataclass` decorator.
To make things even easier for the user, I would like the user to have only to use my decorator so that his/her class is decorated with `@dataclass`.

So here is what I have come up with to decorate a class, so that the decorated class has a new attribute `id_`. I am submitting this code to know if the nesting of decoartor is 'acceptable'?
Basically, I am not so sure about calling a decorator like a function (while it is a function), so I wonder if there could be side effects?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

# My library: complexitiy is allowed.
def indexer(orig_class):
    orig_class = dataclass(orig_class)
    # Copy of original __init__ to call it without recursion.
    orig_init = orig_class.__init__
    id_ = 10

    def __init__(self,*args, **kws):
        self.id_ = id_
        orig_init(self, *args, **kws) # Call the original __init__

    orig_class.__init__ = __init__ # Set the class' __init__ to the new one

    return orig_class

# User environment: importing @indexer decorator: ease of use is targeted.
# Expected behavior is that @indexer provides same functions as @dataclass.
@indexer
class Truc:
    mu : int

# Test
test = Truc(3)

test.mu
Out[37]: 3

test.id_
Out[38]: 10
```

As a sidenote, I don't know if decorator is better than class inheritance here, when it comes to adding attributes and methods?
Thanks for the advices!
Bests,

#### Edit

To whom may read till here, and wonder about use between decorator and inheritance.

Going farther in the implementation, I finally stick with decorator as it seems to me it provides a more flexible way of tweaking what would have been a child class if had retained inheritance.

With inheritance, I don't see how the parent class has any control on child attributes (to make them frozen for instance) while leaving complete freedom on how naming/defining these attributes.

But this is actually an important property I am looking for with dataclass.

So, current status is reviewable with below `@indexer`decorator.
It leaves freedom to the user to create a 'data class' with the number of parameters he/she wants, naming them as he/she wants.
But it makes possible

- to compare and check equality between 2 instances of decorated class.
- once an instance is created from decorated class, it cannot be modified (frozen)
- it equips the decorated class with a (modifiable when decorating) attribute `fields_sep`
- it equips the decorated class with a method to print as string parameters value defined when instancing the decorated class, and not those added by the decorator (like `fields_sep`)

It fulfills my requirements (I can use the objects created from decorated class) as keys for a dict or sorted dict.

In case it can help, here it is.

PS: if you have any advises or better practices, I welcome them.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

# for optional arguments in decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617244/4442753
def indexer(index_class=None, *, fields_sep:str='.'):
    def _tweak(index_class):
        # Wrap with `@dataclass`.
        index_class = dataclass(index_class, order= True, frozen=True)
        # Copy of original __init__ to call it without recursion.
        index_class_init = index_class.__init__
    
        def __init__(self,*args, **kws):
            object.__setattr__(self, "_fields_sep", fields_sep)
            index_class_init(self, *args, **kws)
    
        index_class.__init__ = __init__
    
        def _to_str(self):
            return self._fields_sep.join(map(str, asdict(self).values()))
    
        index_class._to_str = property(_to_str)
    
        return index_class
    if index_class:
        # Calling decorator without other parameters.
        return _tweak(index_class)
    # Calling decorator with other parameters.
    return _tweak

# Test without parameter.
@indexer
class Test:
    mu : int
    nu : str
test = Test(3, 'oh')
assert test._to_str == '3.oh'

# Test with 'fields_sep' parameter.
@indexer(fields_sep='-')
class Test:
    mu : int
    nu : str
test = Test(3, 'oh')
assert test._to_str == '3-oh'

# Test (un)equality.
@indexer
class Test:
    mu : int
    nu : str
test1 = Test(3, 'oh')
test2 = Test(3, 'oh')
assert test1 == test2
test3 = Test(4, 'oh')
assert test1 != test3

# Test dict.
di = {test1:[1,2,3], test2:[7,8,9]}
assert len(di) == 1
assert di[Test(3, 'oh')] == [7,8,9]
```

Comment: I'm not an expert but I'd say a simple inheritance is the natural way of achieving that. Using a decorator would never come to my mind

Comment: You want to use inheritance here.  Absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, I am not so sure about calling a decorator like a function
> (while it is a function), so I wonder if there could be side effects?

*decorators* in `python` are *syntactic sugar*, [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) in *Motivation* gives following example

```
def foo(cls):
    pass
foo = synchronized(lock)(foo)
foo = classmethod(foo)
```

is equivalent to

```
@classmethod
@synchronized(lock)
def foo(cls):
    pass
```

In other word decorators allow you to write less lines of codes for getting very same result.